# How do play local video file in Electron

Tags: javascript, video, electron

I try do learn Electron and want play local video file. I have follow all examples I find but all are dates from 5 more years and not work. Why no work example of regular job?

Sorry for English bad.

I try to use `<input type="file" id="video-input" />` and get good path to file: `files[0].path` but when use in `<source kind="video/mp4" src={video} />` nothing work.

I try to add:

```
protocol.handle('media-loader', (request) => {
  return net.fetch(`media-loader://${request.url.slice('media-loader://'.length)}`);
});
```

I find https://github.com/amilajack/erb-video-example and add changes from https://github.com/amilajack/erb-video-example/commit/0706e53795dc11b4d8a0932b3a9d6de572de6c71#diff-d9d75cc1dda9c5e912390983ac6b263a

Nothing works. Cannot find example not over 5 years old.

**UPDATED**

I restart environment and `files[0].path` work with `webPreferences.webSecurity = false`, but on `true` and added `media-loader://` prefix nothing. I add console log in custom protocol:

```
protocol.handle('media-loader', (request) => {
  console.log(`media-loader://${request.url.slice('media-loader://'.length)}`);
  return net.fetch(`media-loader://${request.url.slice('media-loader://'.length)}`);
});
```

and see in terminal constant logs of: `media-loader://C/Users/johnnyT/project/data/video/sample.mp4`

until close app.

Comment: Saying "nothing work" is not helpful, you should share the error(s) you get.

Comment: No errors. When errors I can fix. This why I ask.

Comment: Are you sure you are looking in the `dev` console and not jsut the terminal?

Comment: Yes, both ok. Electron is dead? Why no practiced examples in long time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a basic example to play video in electron:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Local Video Player</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <video id="video-player" controls></video>
        <script src="renderer.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

`renderer.js`:

```
    
    const videoPlayer = document.getElementById('video-player');
    
    // Listen for the 'play-video' event from the main process
    ipcRenderer.on('play-video', (event, filePath) => {
        // Set the video source to the local file path
        videoPlayer.src = filePath;
    });
    `
    main.js : `const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron');
    const path = require('path');
    const url = require('url');
    
    let mainWindow;
    
    function createWindow() {
        mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
            width: 800,
            height: 600,
            webPreferences: {
                nodeIntegration: true
            }
        });
    
        // Load the HTML file
        mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
            pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
            protocol: 'file:',
            slashes: true
        }));
    
        // Open DevTools
        mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
    }
    
    app.on('ready', createWindow);
    
    // Listen for the 'open-file-dialog' event from the renderer process
    ipcMain.on('open-file-dialog', (event) => {
        // Show a dialog to select a video file
        dialog.showOpenDialog(mainWindow, {
            properties: ['openFile'],
            filters: [
                { name: 'Videos', extensions: ['mp4', 'avi', 'mov', 'mkv'] }
            ]
        }).then(result => {
            if (!result.canceled && result.filePaths.length > 0) {
                // Send the selected file path to the renderer process
                mainWindow.webContents.send('play-video', result.filePaths[0]);
            }
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    });
    `
    Trigger the file dialog: 
    
        const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
        
        // Trigger the file dialog
        ipcRenderer.send('open-file-dialog');
```

Comment: good simple implement. thanks. do know how to do `webPreferences.webSecurity = true` for packaged?

Comment: you can use this sample code to get the reference: const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

app.on('ready', () => {
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      webSecurity: true
    }
  })

  // Load your HTML file
  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')
})

Comment: not work for `webPreferences.webSecurity = true` but answers question. will create new for security issue on future.